# How to access a variable in initializer file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rpx

I have Devise and Devise_RPX_Connectable (https://github.com/chrisdebruin/devise_rpx_connectable) working (users can login with their facebook account). I'm using

```
rails -v 2.3.5 devise --version 1.0.8 devise_rpx_connectable --version 0.1.3
```

My question is how do I access the advanced user information in my controllers? Specifically the ones listed below are in my devise.rb file in the initializers directory.

```
config.rpx_auto_create_account = true # false if you don't want to create users automaticaly. True by default. 
config.rpx_additional_user_data = [:verifiedEmail, :url, :providerName,:photo] # default [], get some extra profile info from RPXnow, default only a few fields are available in the rpx_user object (https://rpxnow.com/docs#profile_data) 
config.rpx_extended_user_data = true # false by default, extended data only available for Plus and Pro RPX users (https://rpxnow.com/docs#api_auth_info)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked out the Devise source and it looks like those are using Rails' [mattr_accessor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-mattr_accessor) method which should expose them publicly on the Devise module. You should be able to access them like so:

```
Devise.rpx_auto_create_account # returns true
```

Comment: Glad I could help! You can accept the answer to let others know your question has been resolved.